# Rubymine: is it missing some key Git functionality available on Eclipse team provider?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, ide, rubymine

I am still on the lookout for a Eclipse-like ROR IDE (at least it should have the functions that I am more or less used to having), and have decided to conduct a trial of RubyMine.

Unfortunately I quickly discovered two things:

1. Git log/history view: There isn't an equivalent for `Link with Editor and Selection` (it's the function that allows the history to be updated and limited to changes applicable to the active document at any point in time)

**The closest is a per document history on separate tabs, there is no linking with editor or selection.**

1. There is no way to reset to a particular commit (or branch from it) by right clicking on it. Is it really worse than gitk in this regard?!

**Reset/branch at a particular commit is not possible at the Changes or the Version Control view (though possible via Checkout/Reset Head with ability to specify commit hashes). The context integration has room for improvement in this regard.**

I would be very glad to be proven wrong on either/both counts.

**Edit: Updated with input from CrazyCoder**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. There is no exactly this feature, but there is **Show History** from the file context menu. Multiple history tabs can be switched between in the **Version Control** panel.
2. **Changes** | **Log** panel has these actions in the context menu (**New Branch**, **Checkout Revision**).

Comment: Looks like I missed the "VCS Operations Popup...", I suppose this is the context menu? Is there any way I can evoke it via right-click?

Comment: Right click, Git, Show History.